# Php5-fpm too much memory usage nginx and ubuntu 11.04 32bit

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, memory, php-fpm, outofmemoryerror

I recently got vps with 512MB ram. I install nginx 1.2.4 with ph5-fpm and a simple wordpress installation . I currently have no traffic as its in development mode.But still It shows 495MB used and 80% of 495 is used by php5-fpm.

What could be the issue to cure this,As in apache i didn't have any problem like this.

From the first website loading php5-fpm memory usage started to increase.

I tried memory showing using python script by http://www.pixelbeat.org/scripts/ps_mem.py

It shows that max ram is used by php5-fpm.

Suggest me a way so that, my site can handle traffic as wordpress use too much resources but not this much.

Comment: Post your nginx config, php-fpm config and top output during the peak. You may want to use something like pastebin for conservation of question space.

Comment: @Grumpy here is link http://pastebin.com/wSZyZ3TE
Help me to sort out the issue. Thanks

Comment: (1) Your keepalivetimeout is uselessly long. Try something like 5. (2) you actually didn't include any relevant section for your php-fpm. Your relevant config is in `/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/*.conf` and that's not top. Type `top` in shell and paste ALL of it.

Comment: @Grumpy hi, i updated with the www.conf in pool.d dir in fpm 
the link is http://pastebin.com/L0p1wC6c
thanks for your help, i really appreciate it.

Comment: I see you have yet to follow up from my answer. Update your www.conf to the values I outlined in the answer previously and then post your top -- which you still not have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A 512MB ram is tiny, expectations of running a "large traffic" is illogical.

Because you provided nearly no details other than how much ram your php-fpm uses on idle... I can only really suggest one thing. Try setting a lower pm.max_requests value in php-fpm settings. Like...

```
pm.max_requests = 100
pm.max_children = 5
```

If you want to understand the php-fpm settings in more detail, you can [look at this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/460922/php5-fpm-configuration-pm-node-process-manager-settings-nodes-in-more-layman).

Comment: yeah correct i didn't specified other parameters. also as stated in case of apache2 i could handle much more traffic than in this case.Sometimes only few processing lead to out of memory error.And i am not able to figure it out, whats the problem.

Comment: hi i changed the max request and max children to what you stated, but, there is no effect, the website still have no traffic. if it has, there it shows only minor change.
here are values from top
http://pastebin.com/f4uBb4JT
Hope you can see that php5-fpm is taking ram much than expected.

Comment: @AbhishekGahlot You need to restart php-fpm (`service php-fpm restart`) anytime you change your configuration. I see that you have not. Additionally, when including top, don't strip out the stuff on the top.